# Django deployment in openshift taking too long than normal

Tags: django, openshift, postgresql-9.2

Django 1.5.4 app with postgres 9.2 cartridge is taking simply too long to deploy after each push, the git remote console message gets stuck in "Preparing build for deployment" state always. What might be the problem ?

And the same deployment is running fine in single gear app. But the multi-gear app is giving this problem.

Comment: Actually I have the same issue with single gear app. It just takes too long to be effective for frequent deployments. Even when hot deploy is enabled.

Comment: The same for my nodejs app

Comment: anything new here? My deployment also hangs after `Preparing build for deployment` :(